# Why Quartus Prime does not want to ignore systemverilog assertion used for simulation?

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I have following property declaration and check in one of my system verilog files:

```
   property StepOutP_pulse_width;
      int count;
      @(posedge ClkRs_ix.clk)
    ($rose(mc.outvec.StepOutP_o),count=STEPPER_PULSE_WIDTH) |->
      (mc.outvec.StepOutP_o,count--)[*] ##1 (~mc.outvec.StepOutP_o && count==0);
   endproperty // StepOutP_pulse_width
   assert property (StepOutP_pulse_width);
```

This basically checks the width of a pulse generated by signal mc.outvec.StepOutP_o

When I try to compile the design, Quartus Prime fails on this property declaration saying

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at steppingcontroller.sv(404)
>   near text: "]";  expecting an operand. Check for and fix any syntax
>   errors that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword. The
>   Intel FPGA Knowledge Database contains many articles with specific
>   details on how to resolve this error. Visit the Knowledge Database at
>   https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/search.html
>   and search for this specific error message number.

Now, I would be thinking, that during analysis&synthesis these property declarations and associated assertions are *completely ignored* as they only concern simulation. But apparently it is not the case. Modelsim (original mentor graphics version) does not have a problem to compile it, and as well the assertion does what is expected. Quartus verilog compilation settings are set to 'SystemVerilog'

How to:

- make the property specification compliant with quartus compiler?
- or setup compiler to ignore these assertions?

Thanks

Comment: all methodology i've been working with suggest putting `ifdef/`ifndef around assertion code. So, you can do it. It is preferred over using translate on/off directives.

Comment: The error message suggests it is treating the file as Verilog instead of SystemVerilog.  If you comment out the assertions, do it accept other SystemVerilog keywords such as `always_comb` and `always_ff`?

Comment: I have checked, and Quartus compiler is really setup in SystemVerilog mode. Unless there is another setting than Assignments/Settings/Compiler Settings/Verilog HDL input. What is exact reason why ifdef should be prefered method over on/off directives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use synthesis directives. You can specify synthesis translate_off and synthesis translate_on as shown below:

```
// synthesis translate_off    
property StepOutP_pulse_width;
      int count;
      @(posedge ClkRs_ix.clk)
    ($rose(mc.outvec.StepOutP_o),count=STEPPER_PULSE_WIDTH) |->
      (mc.outvec.StepOutP_o,count--)[*] ##1 (~mc.outvec.StepOutP_o && count==0);
   endproperty // StepOutP_pulse_width
   assert property (StepOutP_pulse_width);    
// synthesis translate_on
```

Any code written between the translate_off , translate_on comments is ignored by the compiler. Please note that this feature can be disabled/enabled by setting the option [ignore_translate_off_and_synthesis_off](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/quartushelp/current/index.htm#logicops/logicops/def_ignore_translate_off.htm)